# Giant Reign shock travel?

Tags: mountain-bike, shocks, giant

I've just bought a Fox Float X 2014 for my 2015 Giant Trance. It fits my Trance perfect but I may be upgrading to a 2015 Giant Reign. I was thinking would my shock fit onto a reign? The size of mine is 200x57 (7.825" x 2.25"). Does anyone know the size of a reign?
Cheers

Comment: What's wrong with the stock suspension on these four and six thousand dollar bicycles?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Because I have a better shock on my current bike, wouldn't you rather something better for no extra cost?